# Переадресация email средствами PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail, phpmailer

Мой сайт получает email на адрес "user@mysite.ru", и я желаю совершить переадресацию этого сообщения на реальный почтовый адрес пользователя (скажем, "real_mail@mail.com") средствами PHP (в данном случае PHP производит дополнительную обработку сообщения, так что пересылка через настройки SMTP невозможна).

Мне удалось осуществить пересылку, но при этом в получатель видит в письме в пункте "Кому" почту "real_mail@mail.com", в то время как требуется, чтобы в качестве получателя был указан адрес, с которого произведена пересылка, т. е. "user@mysite.ru".

```
    $fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

    $parser = new MailMimeParser();

    $message = $parser->parse($fp);

    $stmt = safeq("SELECT local_email FROM users WHERE email = ?", "s", $message->getHeaderValue("From"));
    $stmt->bind_result($from);
    if(!$stmt->fetch())
        fail();
    $stmt->close();

    $to = [];
    $toheaders = array($message->getHeader("To"));
    if($message->getHeader("CC"))
        $toheaders[] = $message->getHeader("CC");
    foreach($toheaders as $toheader)
        if(isset($toheader))
            foreach($toheader->getAddresses() as $addr)
                $to[] = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE local_email = '".$db->escape_string(str_replace("@mysite.ru", "", $addr))."'";

    $resp = $db->query(join(" UNION ", $to));
    if(!$resp)
        fail();
    $to = [];
    while($result = $resp->fetch_assoc())
        $to[] = $result["email"];
    if(sizeof($to) == 0)
        fail();

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->Host = 'mysite.ru';
    $mail->setFrom("$from@mysite.ru");
    $mail->Subject = $message->getHeaderValue('Subject');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = $message->getHTMLContent();
    $mail->AltBody = $message->getTextContent();
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

    foreach($message->getAllAttachmentParts() as $part)
        $mail->addStringAttachment($part->getBinaryContentStream(), $part->getFilename());

    fclose($fp);

    foreach($to as $addr) {
        $mail->addAddress($addr);
        $mail->send();
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients( );
    }
```

Comment: В каком виде письмо? `.eml`?

Comment: cPanel перенаправляет письмо в сыром виде на PHP скрипт. На данный момент я просто достаю из письма важные заголовки с помощью mail-mime-parser, а затем пересобираю письмо с некоторыми изменениями и отсылаю через PHPMailer.

Comment: Я в принципе делал то же самое, но на NodeJS. Нужно удалить/поменять заголовки: `Message-Id:` (это крайне важно, столкнулся с некорректным поведением Яндекс почты, если слать два письма с одинаковым полем), `DKIM-Signature:`, `From:`, `To:`, `Return-Path:`. Этого было достаточно, чтобы входящее письмо оказалось с тем же содержимым, подписанное (я шлю не сразу, а на свой релей, но думаю через PHP можно также подписать), но с другим From и To. Вот в моем репо [как это сделано](https://github.com/dbfun/docker.mailtester/blob/master/api/lib/Checkdelivery/Sender.js)

Comment: вы решили свою проблему? мой комментарий помог?

Comment: Нет, проблема не решена. Метод пересылки рабочий, спасибо, но у меня проблема не в самой пересылке, а в том, что я не могу сделать заголовок "To" отличным от получателя (т. е. в письме написано "To: user@mysite.com", а письмо должно отправляться на почту, скажем, "user@mail.com"). Это работает при обычной пересылке, но если встрять с PHP кодом, то ничего не получается.

Comment: Приведите если не сложно, код

Comment: Добавил код, который я использую сейчас.

Comment: Я подкину вам идею. Не знаю, сработает или нет - протестировать возможности нет. Попробуйте реальный адрес получателя добавить с помощью `addBCC("real_mail@mail.com")`, а адрес `user@mysite.ru` установить с помощью `addCustomHeader("To", "user@mysite.ru")`. Таким образом конверт будет содержать `real_mail@mail.com` (что будет использовано для `RCPT TO`), а заголовок - `user@mysite.ru`

Comment: Спасибо, но она не помогает. Точнее, помогает, но только отчасти - во-первых, вызывается рекурсия, а во-вторых, в письме, полученном клиентом, указывается сразу два адреса (настоящий и локальный) несмотря на то, что в отправленном письме получатель был задан как секретный.

Comment: _"вызывается рекурсия"_, _"указывается сразу два адреса"_. Значит `PHPMailer` делает `RCPT TO` для двух адресов. Если вы не допустили ошибку, то похоже на некорректное поведение `PHPMailer`, либо у них так специально предусмотрено по каким-то причинам.

Comment: PHPMailer использует функцию `mail`, которая, по видимому, сама автоматически импортирует адресата из заголовка "To". Но, кстати, я заметил, что `mail` также принимает дополнительные аргументы для консольной команды - я искал способ этим воспользоваться, но не удалось...

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, я сделал небольшое исправление в коде ответа. Вместо `trim($header[1])` лучше использовать `$this->encodeHeader(trim($header[1]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно осуществить силами `PHPMailer` при условии, что вы используете `SMTP` как механизм отправки, то есть:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
```

Идея такая: необходимо реальный адрес получателя (`real_mail@mail.com`) установить как `BCC`, а его "виртуальный" адрес (`user@mysite.ru`) установить как заголовок с помощью метода `addCustomHeader('To', 'user@mysite.ru')`.

Таким образом, конверт будет адресован `real_mail@mail.com`, и доставка будет производиться на этот адрес. А в заголовке `To` будет указано `user@mysite.ru`, что и будет отображено конечному пользователю в его почтовом клиенте.

Правда, здесь есть один нюанс, который нужно исправить. `PHPMailer` устроен так, что если при подготовке письма к отправке не установлены поля `To` и `Cc`, то будет добавлен заголовок `To: undisclosed-recipients:;` (см. метод [`createHeader()`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/c5e61d0729507049cec9673aa1a679f9adefd683/src/PHPMailer.php#L2381)).

В этом же методе далее будет добавлен и ранее установленный заголовок `To: user@mysite.ru`, что приведёт к наличию двух заголовков `To`. При этом, есть ненулевая вероятность существования анти-спам фильтра где-то на стороне клиента или его провайдера, который не пропустит e-mail, адресованный `undisclosed-recipients`.

Чтобы это исправить, немного допилим метод `createHeader()` (пилить [здесь](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/c5e61d0729507049cec9673aa1a679f9adefd683/src/PHPMailer.php#L2437)):

```
--- a/PHPMailer.php        2019-12-10 06:17:38.000000000 -0500
+++ b/PHPMailer.php        2019-12-21 10:55:24.000000000 -0500
@@ -2435,6 +2435,11 @@

         // Add custom headers
         foreach ($this->CustomHeader as $header) {
+            if ($header[0] === 'To') {
+                $result = str_replace('To: undisclosed-recipients:;', 'To: ' . $this->encodeHeader(trim($header[1])), $result);
+                continue;
+            }
+
             $result .= $this->headerLine(
                 trim($header[0]),
                 $this->encodeHeader(trim($header[1]))
```

Теперь `undisclosed-recipients` будет заменён на пользовательский заголовок `To`, если он был установлен.

Вот скрипт, использованный для тестирования (с изменёнными адресами):

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path_to/phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'path_to/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path_to/phpmailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try
{
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.my.example.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
        $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

        $mail->setFrom('foo@my.example.com', 'Foo');
        $mail->addBCC('real@real.example.org');
        $mail->addCustomHeader('To', 'virtual@my.example.com');

        $mail->Subject = 'Dummy e-mail subject';
        $mail->Body = 'Dummy e-mail body';

        $mail->send();

        echo "Message has been sent\n";
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        echo "Error while sending message: $mail->ErrorInfo\n";
}
```